# Opera is loading my page twice

Tags: asp-classic, include, opera, pageload

My page is loaded twice by Opera. Version 11.11

I have placed some console logs at a few places to indicate the order that parts of my document are being loaded, see below.

```
Console Logs:

Head section
Head section
Inside my Script.js file
Inside my Script.js file
Body section
Body section
Inside jQuery(document).ready
Inside jQuery(document).ready
```

It is a .asp classic page using .shtml and .asp includes, and I am using jQuery for my script.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why Opera could be loading the page twice, when Firefox, Safari, IE, and Chrome are all fine?

If you need more info please ask, I'm not sure how much detail I need to provide in order to get some initial suggestions, I hope the above is enough to get started, thanks.

---

One thing I notice is the order of the outputted console logs. If the page was actually loading twice wouldn't the order be?

```
Console Logs:

Head section    
Inside my Script.js file
Body section
Inside jQuery(document).ready
Head section    
Inside my Script.js file
Body section
Inside jQuery(document).ready
```

Therefore i'm thinking that it's a bug with Opera's console, i.e Dragonfly.

Would anyone tend to agree with that or have any other theories?

Comment: Is the page refreshing or two windows opening or....

Comment: The only indication I have that Opera is loading the page twice is the logs in the console. I was having trouble with a particular function which led me to place some console logs in my script and noticed it outputted twice! I then placed some logs in the head section of my doc, and also within the body of my document. I cleared the console in Opera and refreshed the page. The logs I have shown in my question then outputted. Do you think it may be a bug with Opera's console?

Comment: create a test page with a subset of your code and see if it logs it twice logs it twice

Comment: I created a very very minimal minimal page:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   console.log("Console log in the head section");
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>` , and Opera's console did indeed output that log twice. So I conclude that it's a bug with Dragonfly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a known issue with Opera [Why does console.log prints out twice?](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1055322)

Comment: you can have that answer as accepted as you found a little bit of evidence that its a bug. ;) seems they haven't actually fixed it though as they claimed they had back in July 2011.

Comment: I had 11.11 when it was outputting twice. I just upgraded to 11.64 and it seems it is now fixed.

Comment: Opera 11.11 was released on May 18, 2011 so that fix must have been applied after this